# Why does running flutter drive begin Downloading web sdk?

Tags: flutter, testing, flutter-test

I'm trying to run integration tests with the integration_test package. When I run `flutter drive  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart  --target=integration_test/splash_test.dart` to test my splash screen it says `Downloading Web SDK`. There is no web implementation in my app and the download is taking too long on my connection. Why is this happening and can I skip it to go straight to testing on mobile? Thanks in advance. PS: Even when I run `flutter drive help` it starts downloading this "Web SDK". I'm on the Flutter master channel version 2.1.0-13.0.pre.574.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that since I did not specify which device to run the tests on and the next step in the command flow is selecting a device from a list of potential devices to test on(which includes a web browser); I would assume that is why it had to get the web sdk first and any other sdk that would be required for that list of devices. My assumption is that if I specified my android device in the first command, It would not have needed to download the web sdk. This is all speculation, if you have a surefire answer please feel free to correct me.